# Reordering Cell Icon Customized

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a table view in which i am reordering my cells

Now the issue is that the client doesn't like the icon of the reorder (i.e. 3 horizontal lines)

Is there any way you can help out.

First of all I want to know Is it possible at all?

Comment: Finally came to the decission that Reorder Icons cannot be customized. and rest all things are possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the standard icon. But you should be able to use a custom button and start/end editing mode programmatically (haven't tested this).

If it isn't a very custom UI at all, tell him that messing with standard icons/behavior is the best way to make users frustrated.

Comment: i have tried that too but am unable to remove the minus sign and the horizontal line.. If i set the frame of the button at place of reorder icon still the reorder icon appears above it. Tried every thing. but yet failed :(

Comment: All the things are done except the custom reorder icon(3 horizontal lines). So finally have decided to ask client to accept the standard format. :)